# Registering a C++ sink with C# COM server

Tags: c#, c++, outlook, com, interop

I want to register a C++ sink with an outgoing interface, and therefore events, of a C# application.

The C# application is an addin for Outlook that acts as a COM server which supports incoming and outgoing interfaces. The client of this server is the C++ app which contains the sink, which I am also developing.

I managed to get the incoming interfaces of the COM server (addin) working by registering the addin on the Running Object Table(ROT), retrieving a pointer to the addin from the ROT in the C++ app and then calling the methods of the incoming interface.

The problem occurs when attempting to register the C++ sink to the IConnectionPoint of the relevant interface of the addin.

The following cut down code shows my addin (C# COM server):

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Ole32
    {
        [DllImport("Ole32.Dll")]
        public static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out IBindCtx bindCtx);
        [DllImport("oleaut32.dll")]
        public static extern int RegisterActiveObject
            ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punk,
                ref Guid rclsid, uint dwFlags, out int pdwRegister);
    }

    [ComVisible(true), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComSourceInterfacesAttribute(typeof(_IEvents))]
    public sealed partial class AddIn : IMyInterface, IDisposable
    {
        private int m_cookie = 0;

        public delegate void Event1Delegate();
        public event Event1Delegate Event1;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(
            object sender,
            System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Register this object with the Running Object Table (ROT)
            Guid guid = Marshal.GenerateGuidForType(typeof(IMyInterface));
            Ole32.RegisterActiveObject(this, ref guid, 0, out m_cookie);

            // Register for Outlook quit event
            ((Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_Event)Application).Quit +=
                new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_QuitEventHandler(ThisAddIn_Quit);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Quit()
        {
            Logger.Log("ThisAddIn_Quit():");
            Dispose();
        }

        public new void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_cookie != 0)
            {
                IBindCtx bc;
                Ole32.CreateBindCtx(0, out bc);

                IRunningObjectTable rot;
                bc.GetRunningObjectTable(out rot);
                rot.Revoke(m_cookie);
                m_cookie = 0;
            }

            base.Dispose();
        }

        public void IncomingInterfaceMethod()
        {
            if (Event1 != null)
            {
                Logger.Log("Firing Event");
                Event1();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The .idl for the interfaces MyInterface and _IEvents is as follows:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(a817e7a2-43fa-11d0-9e44-00aa00b6770a),
    dual,   
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IComponentRegistrar : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] HRESULT Attach([in] BSTR bstrPath);
    [id(2)] HRESULT RegisterAll();
    [id(3)] HRESULT UnregisterAll();
    [id(4)] HRESULT GetComponents([out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* pbstrCLSIDs, [out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* pbstrDescriptions);
    [id(5)] HRESULT RegisterComponent([in] BSTR bstrCLSID);
    [id(6)] HRESULT UnregisterComponent([in] BSTR bstrCLSID);
};

[
    object,
    uuid(6C032E68-4DF7-49BE-9949-88F8AADD3D40),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IMyInterface : IDispatch
{
    [id(1)] void IncomingInterfaceMethod();
};

[
    uuid(D3E30009-BF30-4BFD-BF4D-88306D90CA0F),
    version(1.0),
    custom(a817e7a1-43fa-11d0-9e44-00aa00b6770a,"{43B9624D-0143-438F-A5B1-7CC09F733476}")
]
library MyComLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(43B9624D-0143-438F-A5B1-7CC09F733476)      
    ]
    coclass CompReg
    {
        [default] interface IComponentRegistrar;
    };

    [
        uuid(D2A0BE8B-BB05-4472-9976-D17AD5EBDABD)      
    ]
    dispinterface _IEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(1)] void Event1();
    };

    [
        uuid(76ED50BC-5DE0-43DA-83FA-5CD44E88B481)
    ]
    coclass MyInterface
    {
        [default] interface IMyInterface;
        [default, source] dispinterface _IEvents;
    };
};
```

This is defined in an ATL project and built into a .dll and registered. This is then referenced in the addin C# project.

Finally the C++ app sink header looks like this:

```
class MySink : public _IEvents
{
public:
    ...

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, AddRef)()
    {
        InterlockedIncrement(&m_refCount);

        return m_refCount;
    }

    STDMETHOD_(ULONG, Release)()
    {
        InterlockedDecrement(&m_refCount);

        if (m_refCount == 0)
        {
            delete this;
            return 0;
        }

        return m_refCount;
    }

    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID riid, void ** ppvObject)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown)
        {
            *ppvObject = (IUnknown*)this;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        if ((riid == IID_IDispatch) || (riid == __uuidof(_IEvents)))
        {
            *ppvObject = (IDispatch*)this;
            AddRef();
            return S_OK;
        }

        return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfoCount)(UINT* /*pctinfo*/)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetTypeInfo)(UINT /*itinfo*/, LCID /*lcid*/, ITypeInfo** /*pptinfo*/)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    STDMETHOD(GetIDsOfNames)(REFIID /*riid*/, LPOLESTR* /*rgszNames*/, UINT /*cNames*/, LCID /*lcid*/, DISPID* /*rgdispid*/)
    {
        return E_NOTIMPL;
    }

    STDMETHOD(Invoke)(
        DISPID dispidMember,
        REFIID /*riid*/,
        LCID /*lcid*/,
        WORD /*wFlags*/,
        DISPPARAMS* pdispparams,
        VARIANT* /*pvarResult*/,
        EXCEPINFO* /*pexcepinfo*/,
        UINT* /*puArgErr*/)
    {
        return m_eventCB(dispidMember, pdispparams);
    }

    bool SetupConnectionPoint(IMyInterface* myInterface);

private:
    bool CheckResult(HRESULT hr, std::wstring errMsg);

    ULONG m_refCount;
    EventCB m_eventCB;
    DWORD m_eventCookie = 0u;
    IConnectionPoint* m_connectionPoint = nullptr;
    IUnknown* m_ftm = nullptr;
};
```

Here is the source for MySink:

```
...

// myInterface is retrieved from ROT and then passed here    
bool MySink::SetupConnectionPoint(IMyInterface* myInterface)
{
    // Don't know if this is necessary
    CoCreateFreeThreadedMarshaler(this, &m_ftm);

    HRESULT hr;
    IConnectionPointContainer*  pIConnectionPointContainerTemp = nullptr;
    hr = myInterface->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&pIConnectionPointContainerTemp);


    if (!CheckResult(hr, L"Failed to retrieve ConnectionPointContainer") || !pIConnectionPointContainerTemp)
    {
        return false;
    }

    pIConnectionPointContainerTemp->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(_IEvents), &m_connectionPoint);
    pIConnectionPointContainerTemp->Release();
    pIConnectionPointContainerTemp = nullptr;

    if (m_connectionPoint)
    {
        m_connectionPoint->Advise(this, &m_eventCookie);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool MySink::CheckResult(HRESULT hr, std::wstring errMsg)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Used for logging
        _com_error comError(hr);

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

MySink::SetupConnection() seems to be working with m_connectionPoint being populated and Advise() being called on it. When debugging the addin and calling IncomingInterfaceMethod() from the C++ app, Event1 is still null and so is not called. My guess is the registration between MySink and the addin is not working correctly and so Event1 is always null. Maybe a problem with the Runtime Callable Wrapper?

I had to refactor the code so there may be naming mistakes.

Comment: You might consider implementing ATL's [`IDispEventImpl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7eecxta.aspx) or [`IDispEventSimpleImpl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwy24613.aspx) in your client, instead of creating your own sink. Check [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194179) tutorial for an example.

Comment: Thanks useful tutorial